# Using "Next Page" in while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, get, iteration

I am retrieving data from an API endpoint which only allows me to retrieve a maximum of 100 data points at a time. There is a "next page" field within the response which I could use to retrieve the next 100 data points and so on (there are about 70,000 in total) by plugging the next page url back into the GET request. How can I utilize a for loop or while loop to retrieve all the data available in the endpoint by automatically plugging the "next page" URL back into the get request?

Here is the code im using. The problem is when I execute the While loop I get the same response everytime because it is running on the first response instance. I can't think of the solution of how to adjust this.

```
response = requests.get(url + '/api/named_users?limit=100', headers=headers)
users = []
resp_json = response.json()
users.append(resp_json)

while resp_json.get('next_page') != '':
    response = s.get(resp_json.get('next_page'), headers = headers)
    resp_json = response.json()
    users.append(resp_json)
```

To summarize: I want to take the "next page" URL in every response to get the next 100 data points and append it to a list each time until I have all the data fetched.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, with a recursive function.
For example something like this :

```
response = requests.get(url + '/api/named_users?limit=100', headers=headers)
users = []
resp_json = response.json()
users.append(resp_json)
users = next_page(resp_json.get('next_page'), users)

def next_page(url, users):
    if url != '':
        response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
        resp_json = response.json()
        users.append(resp_json)
        if resp_json.get('next_page') != '':
            return next_page(resp_json.get('next_page'), users)

        return users
```

But in general, APIs return a total number of items and a number of items per request. So you can easily paginate and loop through all items.
Here is some pseudo-code :

```py
for i in range(items_returned__per_request, total_number_of_items/items_returned__per_request):
    response = s.get(resp_json.get('next_page'), headers=headers)
    resp_json = response.json()
    users.append(resp_json)
```